# Spring Boot 2 JasperReportsMultiFormatView

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasper-reports

I migrated from spring boot 1.5 to 2.0 and used jasper report. Migration has a problem is The import *org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports* cannot be resolved. my code is

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsMultiFormatView;
```

Can I see how the java package was changed? To be resolve.

Answer (score 8):

Spring Boot 2.0 uses Spring Framework 5.0 where the support for JasperReports was removed. The package `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports` is no longer available.

As per [Upgrading to Spring Framework 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x):

> The Spring Framework no longer supports: Portlet, Velocity, JasperReports, XMLBeans, JDO, Guava (replaced by the Caffeine support). If those are critical to your project, you should stay on Spring Framework 4.3.x (supported until 2020). Alternatively, you may create custom adapter classes in your own project (possibly derived from Spring Framework 4.x).